# Which is the subject in "Because he felt tired was not a reason for skipping class"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Because he felt tired was not a reason for skipping class.

I am confused which is the subject. Is "Because he felt tired" the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Here, ***Because he felt tired* is the subject of the sentence**. It's the same as saying "The reason he gave was not a reason for skipping class." You're just replacing *the reason he gave* with the actual reason that he gave.

Comment: I didn't downvote because the I agree that it 'sounds alright,' but I don't think putting the subject phrase in quotes is necessary. I agree with @F.E. - Although it does make the structure easier to understand and would be far more common, it is not necessarily a spoken or thought-to-oneself phrase. It is a usage outlier.

Comment: @HowardPautz The original question has since been changed, so I've removed the bit about the quotations. What do you mean by "usage outlier"? Like something that isn't commonly used but is still okay to use?

Comment: +1 Egghead99, better would have been simply 'rare'. I racked my brain trying to find one more example of this construction, but being too lazy was a good excuse. Oh, wait ! :-P